# How to get latest post url in blogger

Tags: html, blogger

I use a notification bar for my blog which contain a link for latest post. The problem is that I have to update it manually everytime I post something . Is there any method by which blogger will automatically set the url of that link every time I post anything?

Comment: using RSS you get latest post of your blogpost

Comment: Question remains, HOW?

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this by using feed and JavaScript for this. The code will look like -

```
<script>
 function recentPostLink(posts){
 var link = posts.feed.entry[0].link[4].href;
 document.querySelector('.recent').href = link; // The class present on anchor tag
 }
</script>
<script src='https://yourblogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json&amp;max-results=1&amp;callback=recentPostLink' />
```

Comment: Wouldn't that work?
`document.querySelectorAll('.post a')[0].href;`

Comment: @AryanAnkitRaj can you share the blog URL, where you are testing this code?

Comment: As the class on the anchor tag is `link`, then code needs to change accordingly -  `document.querySelector('.link').href = link;`

Comment: i changed class on anchor link to recent, but it didn't  worked, so i changed it back to link,

Comment: <script> function recentPostLink(posts){var link = posts.feed.entry[0].link[4].href;
 document.querySelector('.recent').href = link;
 }
</script><script src='https://lovedbs.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json&amp;max-results=1&amp;callback=recentPostLink'/>
<strong><span id='bn-lts'> Latest:</span></strong> <a class='link recent' href='/2017/08/august-schedules-and-details.html'>AUGUST SCHEDULES AND MAJOR SPOILERS </a>  
| 
<strong><span id='bn-rd'> Recommended: </span></strong><a class='link' href='/2017/08/SSG-vs-SSGSS.html'>SSG VS SSGSS</a>


This is my entire code

Answer (score 0):

use this script to

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><div id="recent-posts"><script language="JavaScript">
home_page = "Enter your blog url here";
numposts = 5;

imgr = new Array();showRandomImg = false;boxwidth = 255;cellspacing = 6;borderColor = "#232c35";bgTD = "#000000";thumbwidth = 0;thumbheight = 0;fntsize = 15;acolor = "#666";aBold = true;icon = " ";text = false;showPostDate = false;summaryPost = 0;summaryFontsize = 10;summaryColor = "#666";icon2 = " ";</script><script src="http://24work-new.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/24work-blogspot/recent-posts-t/recent-posts-min-1-ycode.js" type="text/javascript"/></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://24work-new.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/24work-blogspot/recent-posts-t/recent-posts-min-3.css" /></div>
```

It look like this

[image]